# ImportError: No module named social_django.middleware

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, python-social-auth

Hello I'm new to python and Django. Currently I'm trying to run a project made in `django 1.10.2` and `python 2.7` in `ubuntu 16.04`. The project uses a module called python-social-auth and when I try to run the project I get the following error:

`python manage.py runserver`

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fb7d118a758>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 39, in inner_run
http_consumer=self.get_consumer(*args, **options),

  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in get_consumer
    return StaticFilesConsumer()

  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 327, in _init_
  self.handler = self.handler_class()

  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 18, in _init_
super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__init__()
  
File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 177, in _init_
   
 self.load_middleware()
  
File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 80, in load_middleware
    
middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  
File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
   
 module = import_module(module_path)
  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

ImportError: No module named social_django.middleware
```

being that I already have the python-social-auth module installed.
Hopefully you can help me in detail to solve this problem because as I told you I am new to using these tools.

Comment: Wich version of `python-social-auth` do you have? Does it support `Django 1.10.2`?

Comment: Is `python-social-auth` installed for python2.7? It can be installed for Python3 and this is why it's not working.